# An exercise in an introduction to the theory of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

4.4 Let $G$ be a finite p-group; show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of G having order $p$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$.

$Z(G)=\left\{x\in G| xy=yx, \forall y\in G \right\}.$

Can you help me solve it and explain in detail? Thank you very much. Good health!

Comment: Not following.  You start by assuming that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and then you want to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: *"show that if  is a normal subgroup of G having order , then  is a subgroup of "*. What do you mean ? If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is a subgroup...

Comment: You must have mixed words: to prove that normal **subgroup** is a subgroup is pretty trivial...

Comment: sorry, prove $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$.

Comment: $Z(G)=\left\{x\in G| xy=yx, \forall y\in G \right\}.$

Comment: Look up group center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the previous exercise (4.3), which states that $K\cap Z(G)\ne 1$ whenever $K\lhd G$. Now $H\cap Z(G)\ne 1$, and so $H\cap Z(G)$ has order $p$. So $H\cap Z(G) = H$.

Hint of Exercise 4.3: $K\lhd G$ implies that $K$ is a union of some conjugacy classes of $G$.

Comment: Sorry, the question seems very stupid. Can you explain why there is this line $H\cap Z(G)=Z(G)$?

Comment: $H\cap Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$, and $H$ is a group of order $p$. Thus either $H\cap Z(G) = 1$ or $H\cap Z(G) = H$. In this case it cannot be $1$, so it is $H$. It's a typo.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish you good luck as you move on to new and different challenges.